# How to create string from array of strings

Tags: c#, linq

I have this array:

[image]

And I need to make from array above string,one string like this:

```
(export_sdf_id=3746) OR (export_sdf_id=3806) OR (export_sdf_id=23) OR (export_sdf_id=6458) OR (export_sdf_id=3740) OR (export_sdf_id=3739) OR (export_sdf_id=3742)
```

Any idea what is the elegant way to implement it?

Comment: what defines whether or not a different array location is used?

Comment: Did you try searching? Please read [ask].

Comment: Why do you need the brackets?

Comment: Why is someone voting to reopen? This question has been asked thousands of times before, and this question does not follow the guidelines found in [ask]. There is no research shown.

Comment: @CodeCaster both given answers are wrong

Comment: here is the correct answer `string result = String.Join(" OR ", idsArr.Select(x => '(' + x + ')'));`

Comment: @CodeCaster looks like you've picked a bad dupe target here; the target involves joining strings without any delimiter, whereas this one needs to wrap them in brackets *and* join them with `OR`s. That warrants a reopen vote, IMO, although there's probably another, better, dupe lying around (and the question certainly ain't *good*).

Comment: @Mark how about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139228/concatenate-string-collection-into-one-string-with-separator-and-delimiters)?

Comment: @CodeCaster looks better. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-method designed for this.

```
var mystring = String.Join(" OR ", idsArr);
```

This will result in the following string:

```
export_sdf_id=3746 OR export_sdf_id=3806 OR export_sdf_id=23 OR export_sdf_id=6458 OR export_sdf_id=3740 OR export_sdf_id=3739 OR export_sdf_id=3742
```

Note that the brackets are omited as they are not needed for your query.

Comment: you are missing brackets (x) or (y)...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [String.Join(String, String[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx), where first parameter is separator between array elements.

```
string result = String.Join(" OR ", sArr);
```